# How to pass a var to an included module?

Tags: ruby, class, module, include

Likely something simple, but I'm a bit confused using ruby `include`:

app.rb:

```
class Controller
  @template_ext = '.slim'
  def template_ext
    '.slim'
  end
  include RenderingHelpers
end
```

rendering_helpers.rb:

```
module RenderingHelpers

  def render(resp_code=200)
    puts @template_ext # Breaks
    puts template_ext() # => '.slim'
    # Not important: 
    path = File.expand_path(find_template())
    tilt = Tilt.new(find_template()).render(self)
    Rack::Response.new tilt, resp_code
  end
```

end

I'm a bit confused why the method `template_ext()` works but a `@template_ext` doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables starting with an `@` sigil are *instance variables*. Instance variables belong to an instance (object), which is why they are called instance variables (duh!).

In this case, there are two objects, `Controller` and the instance of `RenderingHelpers` that you are calling `render` on. They are two different objects, thus, they each have their own distinct sets of instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

For variable, you can make your variable as class variable -

```
 class Controller
   @@template_ext = '.slim'
   def template_ext
     '.slim'
   end
   include RenderingHelpers
 end
```

or you can do -

```
module RenderingHelpers
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do 
    @template_ext = '.slim'
  end

  def render(resp_code=200)
    puts @template_ext # Breaks
    puts template_ext() # => '.slim'
    # Not important: 
    path = File.expand_path(find_template())
    tilt = Tilt.new(find_template()).render(self)
    Rack::Response.new tilt, resp_code
  end    
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the `@template_ext` variable is actually a class level instance variable, which makes it inaccessible by instance methods like `render`.

What you actually want to do is simply remove the `@template_ext` assignment and stick to your method `template_ext`.

[This can teach you more about how Modules in Ruby work](http://jakeyesbeck.com/2015/07/05/composition-in-ruby/)

Comment: Within `render`, `Controller.instance_variable_get(:@template_ext) #=> ".slim"`.